# Upload image after JavaScript changes

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7, image-uploading

I have a Drupal-7 website, and I have created a module, where you upload an image and preview the image before submitting it.

```
<img id="blah" src="sites/all/themes/my_theme/logo.png" alt="default image" />
```

Then, I have some buttons, that call a JavaScript function onclick and dynamically change the border of the uploaded image.

Now, what I want, is that when the user uploads the image, then he submits the form and I upload his image *with* the border he chose.
How can I achieve that?
The submit button and the image upload are called via a php form at my .module file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common algorithm, with many examples in internet, suppoerted browsers are 10 ie and all modern browsers.

```
 1. Convert user selected file to image (img.src = URL.createObjectURL(userSelectedFile))
 2. Load image to html5 canvas (canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image,0,0,width, height)) 
 3. Draw Border on html5 canvas (canvas.getContext("2d").drawRectangle(0,0, width, height))
 4. Convert canvas to blob (canvas.toBlob(function(blob){/** use new blob **/}))
 5. Upload this blob to server by xhr or xhr + FormData
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to process image (add border) on server side.
When user submit form, he send to server side info about which border he have chosen. And using this info you have to change uploaded image by ImageMajick or etc.

Comment: The imagemagick code goes into the .module file when the submit button form is created?It seems very useful but I don't know exactly how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a JavaScript function that onclick will dynamically change the border of the uploaded image

```
function borderColor() {
var color;
// change border color
$("#borderColorPickID").val(color); // pass color to form
}
```

Pass the hexadecimal color value or color name "green,blue" etc. In a hidden input.

```
<img id="blah" src="sites/all/themes/my_theme/logo.png" alt="default image" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="borderColorPick" id="borderColorPickID" />
```

Bind the image name and the color value, server side, to rename the image accordingly.

So if the uploaded image is **upload.png** and the color value is **#00fc00** rename and save the image as **upload___00fc00.png**

Now all you need is a javascript function to get the border color from the new name of the image, create the border and apply it to the image.

```
function applyBorder(imageName) {
//// get color from image name
//// apply border to image 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have a color as border. I use css border-image. Does your answer apply at this case too?

Comment: Yes you can pass the "border-image" name instead of color if it is unique. You can alter the css border-image property with jQuery

Comment: This is a quick workaround to do what you want without having to store information about image and border to your database in your drupal installation.